# Seeing duplicate attributes after deploying Azure functions to slot

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, azure-deployment-slots

After I deploy my functions to a slot, I see 7 errors in the problem tab in my console.

[image]

Can anyone tell me why I'm seeing this?
The functions are deployed and working fine!

Here is my Http trigger:

```
 [FunctionName("StripeConnectWebhook")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
```

Comment: which trigger you are using and are performing any operation in Azure function

Comment: @Sampath I posted my trigger above.

Comment: Hello @user1186050 got the same as  [you](https://i.imgur.com/XijaLim.png) and the deployment got [succeed](https://i.imgur.com/Tl4mf0O.png) and running in [azure](https://i.imgur.com/g0MV7WX.png).

Comment: So, so you think I should ignore these errors?

Comment: In Azure, it is not a problem but locally Remove the duplicate attributes in respective files

Answer (score 0):

Removing the duplicate attributes in respective local files Solves issues after deployment.

[image]

[image]

[image]

- using `func host` start you can run the Function.

[image]

- In local

[image]

- In [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9gKi.png) of Visual Studio Code.
  [image]
- In Azure portal of HTTP Trigger in inputs [body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01dvD.png)

[image]